# Not seeing "Create Graph" and "Add Application" options after installing Neo4j Desktop

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I'm absolutely new to Neo 4j Desktop/ Database. I installed the latest version(1.4.15) and after installing the application on OSX (12.4), i'm not seeing the options to "create a Graph". I followed the steps from here -> https://neo4j.com/download-thanks-desktop/?edition=desktop&flavour=osx&release=1.4.15&offline=false.

I also tried installing it another mac (same OS version) and got the same problem. Am i missing some installation steps because all the get started videos show the option right after installing and opening the application.

This is what i see now
[image]

This is what i expected
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Add Graph` option creates a new graph. You can do it from the `Add` button dropdown, in the recent version.[image]

Use `Local DBMS` option to create a new local database.

Comment: I do not see the add graph in the dropdown in your screenshot.

I see the following 1. Local DBMS 2. Remote Connection 3. File

can you provide the steps where you see it, please?

Thanks!

Comment: The dropdown options are for graph only, local dbms means local graph, so on and so forth